# Vertical align item within <button> as flex item

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a number of buttons with differently sized images inside:

```
<div>
  <button><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt=""></button>
  <button><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" alt=""></button>
  <button><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x50" alt=""></button>
  <button><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt=""></button>
  <button><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" alt=""></button>
</div>
```

So, I want to vertical align those images to the bottom like in the following image:

[image: desired layout]

But no matter what I try the images are always vertically centered:

[image: layout with buttons]

Check out this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7efebwg/

The funny thing is that if I would use `div`s instead of `button`s, everything works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkycyvvf/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeting the `display` property of the buttons to `flex` and using `flex-direction:column` and `justify-content:flex-end` would seem to work.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt=""></button>
  <button><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" alt=""></button>

</div>
```

Comment: I was indeed missing `flex-direction:column`!

Answer (score 2):

Setting the buttons themselves as flex containers and giving the images a `margin-top` of `auto` seems to work:

```
button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

button img {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y7efebwg/1/